# salesforce saving multiple files large in size to amazon s3.

Tags: apex, visualforce, httprequest, aws

I am using Soap request in apex to save files in amazon s3.But I cannot upload the files larger than 1Mb. Is there any way to upload multiple files larger than 1Mb directly in s3 from a visual Force component. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think it is possible if you do it via JS, without apex layer

Comment: thanks can you put some example for this or any link for the help?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240127/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-with-html-javascript-jquery-with-ajax-request-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SOAP protocol is inefficient with binary data. In fact, it has a 33% overhead. You can send larger files in Apex using the REST API. Over the last few months, I've written code in Apex that could send up to 5mb at a time. If you need to send data larger than this, you'll want to use the direct POST option described in the documentation. Basically, you create a pre-auth token and then instruct the browser to send directly to s3.

Comment: Hi fox, thanks I am having the same idea as you have but i am new to s3 and rest so I don't know exactly that how to do it.  so if can you put some example for this or any link for the help?